# Vending Machine in NuSMV

Tags: model-checking, nusmv

I am new to NuSMV, I am trying to create Vending Machine implementation from  Kripke structure, I have three boolean (coin, selection, brewing) as well as three states.However, When I compile the code I receive "Line 25: at token ":": syntax error" If anyone sees any errors in my code I would appreciate the help.

[Kripke structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT5Pw.jpg)

my attempt to write the code is as follow:

```
MODULE main 

VAR 

   location : {s1,s2,s3};
   coin : boolean;
   selection: boolean;
   brweing: boolean;

ASSIGN

   init(location) := s1;
   init(coin) := FALSE;
   init(selection) := FALSE;
   init(brweing) := FALSE;
   next(location) := 
case
    location = s1 : s2;
    TRUE: coin;  
esac;

next(location) :=
case

location = (s2 : s3 & (TRUE: selection));

location = (s2 : s1 & (FALSE: selection) & (FALSE: coin));
esac;
next(location) :=
case

location = (s3 : s3 & (TRUE: brewing));

location = (s3 : s1 & (FALSE: selection) & (FALSE: coin) & (FALSE: brewing));
esac;


-- specification
•   AG [s ⇒ b] whenever a selection is made coffee is brewed for sure.
•   E [(¬s) U (b)] the coffee will not be brewed as no selection were made.
•   EF[b] there is a state where coffee is brewed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line (among others)

```
location = (s2 : s3 & (TRUE: selection));
```

doesn't make much sense. You need only one `next` statement to assign the next `location` from all possible values of `location`. Also, you don't need to declare `coin`, `selection`, and `brewing` as variables. Use `DEFINE` to define their values based on `location`:

```
MODULE main

VAR
   location : {s1,s2,s3};

ASSIGN
  init(location) := s1;
  next(location) :=
  case
    location = s1 : s2;
    location = s2 : {s1,s3};
    location = s3 : {s1,s3};
  esac;

DEFINE
  coin := location = s2 | location = s3;
  -- similarly for selection and brewing
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from the model is that `coin`, `selection` and `brew` are not only labels but events that trigger the transition. If so, I would write the model like this:

```
MODULE main
VAR
    location: {s1, s2, s3};
    coin: boolean;
    selection: boolean;
    brew: boolean;
    abort: boolean;

INIT
    !coin & !selection & !brew;

ASSIGN
    init(location) := s1;
    next(location) := case
        location = s1 & next(coin)      : s2;
        location = s2 & next(selection) : s3;
        location = s2 & next(abort)     : s1;
        location = s3                   : {s1, s3};
        TRUE                            : location;
    esac;
    next(brew) := (next(location) = s3);
    next(coin) := case
        next(state) = s1  : FALSE;
        state = s1        : {TRUE, FALSE};
        TRUE              : coin;
    esac;
    next(selection) := case
        state = s2        : {TRUE, FALSE};
        next(state) = s1  : FALSE;
    esac;
```